# How to replace character inside double quote in javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace parameter of the function in javascript.Eg:

I have one function `DeleteProduct("2")` and in some condition i want to replace the parameter of `DeleteProduct()` function. Like that:

```
DeleteProduct("1")
```

I have tried this(means how i am replacing the parameter value):

```
 $('#Addr1Div').html($('#Addr2Div').html().replace(/"2"/g, '"1"'));
```

But its not working.

I am calling function like that:

```
 <a href='javascript:$.DeleteProduct(\"2\");'>Delete</a>
```

Comment: How and where are you calling the function? inline event? Either way, show the code that calls it

Comment: Sounds like you are doing something very wrong. Are you using e.g. `onclick='DeleteProduct("1")'`? If yes, change it to store the value in a `data-` attribute and update this using `.data()`.

Comment: You have an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should try explaining the bigger picture behind what you're trying to solve, as there might be a much better way to go about it.

Comment: rather than changing the parameter like this you should call the function with required parameter on the basis of your condition

Comment: i agree with @Deepanshu (plus 1 ) you should use params and not hardcoded values and in your js change it.

Comment: I fear your approach is beyond help...

Comment: yes the approach is not correct.But its an existing code and cant change it.So i have to do it with the existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace it exactly in href attribute

```
var newHref = $('a').attr('href').replace(/"2"/g, '"1"');
// or whatever you use to access <a>
$('a').attr('href', newHref);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/QhaWj/)**